# Cleanest way to relocate User Profiles to seperate Raid drive with MAC OS X users RDP to W2K8R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, mac-osx, network-share

I have a company that WANTS to be windows but the Owner....loves his MAC so I now need to migrate all the C:/Users/? folders to the shared drive in a clean way. I have a few ideas of how to do it but was unsure if there was a best practice.

The users keep saving important documents on their desktops and even with begging/pleading/arguing I can not seem to force this habit away so I need to move the users folders to a drive that is a RAID/Share for redundancy reasons.

They all RDP into Windows Server 2008 R2 and access a Windows based software but save important documents in their personal folders and NOT ON THE SHARE...even with the above pleadings...

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Actually relocating the C:\Users is not actually supported after the system is installed.

What I suspect you should be looking at is Setting up [Folder Redirection](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785925%28WS.10%29.aspx) for the Desktop/Documents folders.  If you want to have everything be on a server, then you also will want to setup [roaming profiles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc738596%28WS.10%29.aspx) in addition to folder redirection.  You don't want to have roaming-profiles only, since roaming profiles makes logins very slow as the size of the profile grows.

Comment: Roaming profiles+folder redirection is the de-facto solution for terminal servers. We redirect just about everything, and delete user profiles from the local server when they log off.